# angularJS scope orderBy does not sort children, just the parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

When I used

```
$scope.data = $filter('orderBy')(data,'title');
```

the parent is sorted, the children are not.

What if my array has children? how can I order the parent and the children?

My array:

```
    data = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "abc",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "abc2",
            "items": []
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "abc1",
            "items": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "cde",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "cde2",
            "items": []
          },
          {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "cde1",
            "items": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: most of the time you would do it in the view....however if you want the data source sorted have to iterate each level and sort those levels

Comment: I needed the original scope. How could I do to go ordering at each level? I have 6 levels in my array. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will need a recursive function to walk through every level. Why do you need to do this? If it's needed in order might consider sending it in order if that's viable. Again...it can be ordered in view also

Comment: So I need to have the original scope sorted because I do some other things in my code, like closing the tree and expanding a branch when a child is added to it. Unfortunately, when I sort in my view - using ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'title'" - my original scope is not sorted. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't sort anything within the child's objects.
For sorting within child object sort your 'items' recursively, for each child, with $filter('orderBy') or similar with code bellow use your own custom comparing function.

```
var orderByFieldName = 'title',
    childPropertyForSorting = 'items',
    s = function (a, b) {
        //Revise comparing function depends on direction of sorting and your wishes
        if (a[orderByFieldName] > b[orderByFieldName])
            return 1;
        if (a[orderByFieldName] < b[orderByFieldName])
            return -1;

        return 0;
    },
    f = function (o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(childPropertyForSorting) && o[childPropertyForSorting] instanceof Array) {
            o[childPropertyForSorting].sort(s);
            o[childPropertyForSorting].forEach(f);
        }
    };

if (originalData instanceof Array) {
    originalData.sort(s);
    originalData.forEach(f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this solution! It worked perfectly! It ordered all the children that I have in my tree. But I have 6 levels of children in my tree. This solution would be performative to sort them all? Thank you in advance!

Comment: this solution will sort any amount of levels. if children has property 'items' instance of Array.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest if you are only trying to orderBy in the view to use

data-ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: 'colum you want'"

[Read more about it here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: I also thought about this solution and it is very good, indeed. The only problem is that I need the original scope sorted. With this solution, just the view gets sorted, and the original scope is not. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Reason is the children is in another level and treated just as another key value pair inside that object, you can use the same filter you used inside a for loop that will loop each data array item and sort the children like this :

```
 //filter the parent level by title
 $scope.data = $filter('orderBy')(data,'title');
 //copy the sorted array in temp variable
 var temp = angular.copy($scope.data);
 //sort the children by title while aggregating each array item and then storing the output in $scope.
 for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      $scope.data[i].items = $filter('orderBy')(temp[i].items,'title');
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that I can only have up to 6 levels of children ("items") in my code. This way, wouldn't I lose performance using 'for'? Is there a way to apply sorting to all children levels without the necessity of chained 'for's? Thanks in advance!